# Javascript - Rigged coin flip (heads first)

Tags: javascript, html

Really basic function, I have a button that simulates a coin flip, I want to always show "heads" first and then randomize after that first input, current code does not work and it randomizes from the first click.

**HTML:**

```
<button id = "riggedCoin" onclick = "riggedCoinFlip()"> Rigged Coin </button>

<h1 id ="h2"> Coin Flip </h1>
```

**JS:**

```
function riggedCoinFlip() {

document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Heads!");

var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

if (coinFace === 0) {
var h1 = document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Heads!");
} else {
var h1 = document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Tails!");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, **`#h2`** element already contains **`Coin Flip`** text. So, we can use this to check for the first time. *We don't need another variable to check it.*

**I've simplified the solution for you. You can try:**

```js
function riggedCoinFlip() {
  var el = document.getElementById("h2");

  if (el.innerHTML === " Coin Flip ") {
    el.innerHTML = "Heads!";
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0
      ? "Heads" : "Tails") +"!";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="riggedCoin" onclick="riggedCoinFlip()">Rigged Coin</button>
<h1 id="h2"> Coin Flip </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one variable and change it after first click, so after that var is changed you can use random.

```js
var random = false;

function riggedCoinFlip() {
  document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Heads!");
  if (random != false) {
    var coinFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (coinFace === 0) {
      var h1 = document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Heads!");
    } else {
      var h1 = document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ("Tails!");
    }
  }
  random = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="riggedCoin" onclick="riggedCoinFlip()">Rigged Coin</button>
<h1 id="h2"> Coin Flip </h1>
```